# Valuable but free

Tags: riddle

> There are normally four of me,
>   Except in two places where there are only one of me,
>   But not the One of me that is actually four.
>
> Important people are paid lots of money to give me,
>   To people who are paid even more to take me,
>   Even though normal people will give me for free.
>
> Who/what am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Direction

There are normally four of me,

> N/S/E/W

Except in two places where there are only one of me,

> From the North Pole, you can only go South, and vice versa

But not the One of me that is actually four.

> The band One Direction has four people

Important people are paid lots of money to give me,

To people who are paid even more to take me,

> Lots of examples, best one so far could be actors and directors (thanks to Kate Gregory)

Even though normal people will give me for free.

> People give direction/advice to others all the time.

Comment: for the important/paid more I believe npgbef znxr zber zbarl guna qverpgbef